# TypeaHead Not working on getting data from database

Tags: php, json, typeahead

I am working on jquery typeahead

```
 $('#country_v1-query<?= $i  ?>').typeahead({
                            order: "desc",
                                    source: {
                                    data: [
                                            "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Afdorra"
                                    ]
                                    },
                                    callback: {
                                    onInit: function(node) {
                                    console.log('Typeahead Initiated on ' + node.selector);
                                    }
                                    }
                            });
```

I want to pass data coming from php like

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
$ar = array('apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'strawberry');
echo json_encode($ar);
```

i want to show this data (json_encode($ar)) in typeahead like

```
data:[<?php echo json_encode($ar);?>]
```

but when i include header of json it render page as json and stop loading HTML and CSS 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Using `implode()` you could output the PHP array as a javascript array in one line :

```php
data: <? echo '["'.implode('","', $ar).'"]'; ?>
```

will produce

```js
data: ["apple","orange","banana","strawberry"]
```